# Why does the fan come on after having my MacBook Air on for only 2 minutes?

Tags: hardware, windows

Running Windows 7 and after a resume the fan comes on about 2 minutes and doesn't turn off and it's the loudest thing in the room. I'm not doing anything but browsing . . and I don't think it's because of flash. Any ideas?

Comment: Is windows the only OS (bootcamp or other) or are you using a virtualization software like Parallels or Fusion?

Comment: Booting directly into Windows with boot camp.

Comment: I would boot back into Mac and see if you can perhaps download newer drivers from Apple. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4407 - Win 7 has really sophisticated power management features, so if the hardware works in Mac - it's either a tuning issue in Windows or the drivers to read the sensors are not working. You can always try to re-install the ones from Apple to make sure they are installed. (great find on the 32/64 bit graphics mode as well)

Answer (score 2):

Windows (in Boot Camp) doesn't do most of the power management tricks OS X does, so the CPU generally runs at full tilt all the time. That creates lots of heat, so your fans stay on. It may be because of flash, but, like you, I doubt it. To test that, leave Windows running for awhile with no web browsing.

Comment: I think a big problem was the video drivers . . . it's a 32-bit Win7 and there are no video drivers installed (just says standard VGA). Found some video drivers and been running windows for a while and it seems to work. I think putting 64-bit Windows might solve all my problems. Just want EVERYONE to be aware that 32-bit Windows in Mac is a bad idea.

Comment: @tooshel That sounds like a good culprit. You should post it as an answer in its own right and then accept it.